# Turn on projectile-mode only for files in actual projects

Tags: projectile

Projectile is pretty great, but I'm finding it difficult to have it turned on only in places where it would be effective.

As I understand it, the two standard choices are to turn it on manually, as in major mode hooks, or to enable it globally with `projectile-global-mode`.  I find the former not broad enough; I want to be able to access projectile commands while visting *any* file in a project, regardless of its type.  But turning the mode on globally is *too* broad; it gets turned on even when visiting such manifestly non-project directories as my home directory, `/tmp`, `/etc`, etc.

Is there a standard way to activate `projectile-mode` only when visiting a file that lives in an actual project, as might be determined by, say, checking for the existence of a `.git`, `.svn`, etc, directory in some ancestor directory of the current file?

Comment: Checking for the existence of `.git`, `.svn`... should be the default. Maybe you have having `projectile-require-project-root` setting to `nil`.

Comment: I just checked, and its value is `t`.  But the mode is still activated in `/etc` for example.

Comment: What's your Projectile version? When you run `projectile-find-files` on such non-project directories, Projectile simply gives you a message "You're no on a project". Are you sure you run the right command?

Comment: Ah, OK, I do see that.  But I still see `Projectile[etc]` in the mode line when I open `/etc`.  It takes up valuable mode line real estate, and I'd rather just not activate the mode at all in non-project directories.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, it's about the modeline. You can set `projectile-mode-line` to check if you are in a project root; if so, displays in the modeline, otherwise displays nothing:

```el
(setq projectile-mode-line
      '(:eval (if (projectile-project-p)
                  (format " Projectile[%s]"
                          (projectile-project-name))
                "")))
```

Comment: That change should be in projectile itself.

Comment: This is definitely useful, but the mode would still technically be active, right?  Ideally the mode would not even be activated in such cases.

Comment: @Sean what's for? There's a reason it's a global minor mode. Is there something get in the way if the global mode is active, aside from the modeline? When the global mode is active, all it does is giving you the Projectile key bindings.

Comment: @abo-abo I also think it should work like this rather than then showing the current `default-directory`. I will make a PR.

Comment: I put this in my init file, and eventually noticed a ton of errors in the `*Messages*` buffer, because `projectile-project-root` raises an exception if called from a non-project directory.  So that function call needs to be wrapped in a `condition-case`, and also `projectile-require-project-root` needs to be bound to `t`.

Comment: @Sean it's done